# how to display an array on a label

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, button, label

I am a beginner and I'd like to print an array on a label by pressing a button.

I already know how to put a String in the label like this:

```
@IBAction func Start(sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = "Insert Array"
```

But instead of "Insert Array" I want to insert my function, which creates an Array at the end.
If I insert the Array, it says:

> use of unresolved identifier 'array'

My code works perfectly in the playground.

Comment: Please show your `my function, which creates an Array at the end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this.

you test() function has NSArray return type

```
func test()-> NSArray{
 //bla bla bla
 let myArray:NSArray = ["data1","data2","data3"]

 print(myArray)
 return myArray;
}
```

then you can get your result

```
label.text = test().componentsJoinedByString(",")
```

Comment: But I don't want to create a new Array.

I got a separate file with a function

    `func test() { 

    bla 

    bla 

    bla 

    print(myArray)

    }`

I can't use "myArray" because it is in that scope, right?

sorry, i'd rather not upload my function :/

Ps: I am still trying to figure out how to format comments :P

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it's that simple. :) 

I forgot to return the array and I didn't declare the type of the function.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to print a non-String variable as a String use `\()`

```
label.text = "\(ArrayFunc())"
```

if this is for troubleshooting purposes use

```
println(ArrayFunc())
//or
println("Array: \(ArrayFunc())")
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. But it returns only "()" as a result

Answer (score -1):

try below code
for(NSString *str in resultArray){

```
    [resultLabel.text= [str stringByAppendingString:@","];

}
```